# Why are bloom filters called "filters"?

Tags: terminology, bloom-filter

Why are bloom filters called "filters".  They behave more like sets, or at least an anonymous set that can be queried for membership.  Where does filter come into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloom filters are called filters because they are often used as a cheap first pass to filter out segments of a dataset that do not match a query.

The earliest reference in [the ACM database](http://dl.acm.org) to a paper with "Bloom Filter" in its title is:

> Lee L. Gremillion, Designing a Bloom filter for differential file
>   access, Communications of the ACM, v.25 n.9, p.600-604, Sept 1982

The earliest reference in the database to a paper with Bloom Filter in its abstract is:

> "A note on the application of differential files to computer aided
>   design" from 1978.

There are earlier papers that are listed as citing the original paper, but none of them cite it in their abstracts and the full texts are behind a pay wall.

Answer (score 5):

Bloom filters answer set membership queries with one-sided error: They can reply that your element is not a member of the set, or that it *may be* a member of the set. This is different from a set data structure, which can answer membership queries precisely. In a typical application, you have a set structure which is costly to query and a bloom filter in addition. You query the bloom filter, if it says "not member" you believe it. If it says "maybe", you query the set.

Comment: Thank you - this matches my intuition.  By any chance do you have any references you can site for this information?

Comment: I was hoping for references that address the etymology.  The references I've checked there don't seem to do so.  The paper that introduced it doesn't use the term filter, but somewhere along the way they became "bloom filters" - I haven't been able to track down the point where that evolved into being.  Any help you can get to track that down would be much appreciated.

Comment: What "bloom" in the name means?

Comment: It's the surname of the person who invented them.